# Ajax not posting data to PHP in JSON object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

i have tried multiple ways using different ajax methods and cant get this to work. I am new to ajax and json so i thought this may be cause the data is not in a form but i have other ajax process's structured the same and they work. the inputs are picked up on click and appears in console but it seems the data: isnt sending the variables to php because when it fails the data returns undefined in alert box. the sql query etc runs fine in php myadmin so im at the end and lost haha! hoping someone can help me!! thanks in advanced!

HTML

```
<?php 
    $page = "Blog | Fakebook"; 
    include "../inc/connect.php"; 
    include "../inc/login-check.php"; 
    include "../inc/header.php";
    include "../inc/menus.php";


?>
<div id="content-wrap" class="create-a-blog">
    <?php
        include "../inc/modals.php"; 
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='author' value='" . $_SESSION['userID'] . "' />"
    ?>
    <div id="hero">
        <a id="ajax-blog-bg" class="btn btn-hollow-wht add-img">Add Image</a>
        <a id="ajax-publish-blog" class="btn btn-hollow-wht pub-blg">Publish Blog</a>
        <section class='create-blog-title'>
            <textarea id="edit-blog-title" name="blog-title" class="title-input" >Enter Blog Title</textarea>
<!--            <p>Date and your name will be shown here</p>-->
        </section>
    </div>  
    <div id="create-blog-content">
        <div class="container rel">
            <article class="article">
                <textarea id="edit-blog-content" rows='4' name='blog-content' cols='50' >Go ahead and get your blog started</textarea>
            </article>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

AJAX

```
$("#ajax-publish-blog").click(function (e){
        event.preventDefault();
        var blogTitle = $('#edit-blog-title').val();
        var content = $('#edit-blog-content').val();
        var image = $('.create-a-blog #hero').css('background-image');
        var cleanup = /\"|\'|\)/g;
        var bg = image.split('/').pop().replace(cleanup, '');
        var authorID = $('input[name=author]').val();
        console.log("Blog Title = " + blogTitle + " // Blog Content = " + content + " // bg image = " + bg + " // authorID =" + authorID);

        $.ajax({
            url: "../process/post-blog-process2.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: { blogTitle: blogTitle, content: content, image: bg, authorID: authorID },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                alert("ohyer" + " " + data.title + " " + data.authorID + " " + data.content + " " + data.image) 
            },
            error: function(data) {
                alert("ohno" + " " + data.title + " " + data.authorID + " " + data.content + " " + data.image)
            }
        });
    });
```

PHP

```
<?php
    session_start(); //start a session  
    include "../inc/connect.php"; //include the database connection 

    //prevent SQL injection and get data from inputs
    $blogTitle = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['blogTitle']);
    $image = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['image']); 
    $content = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['content']); 
    $authorID = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['author']);


    $sql="INSERT INTO blog (blogTitle, image, content, date, authorID) VALUES ('$blogTitle', '$image', '$content', NOW(), '$authorID')";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con)); //run the query 

    if (!$result) {
        $data['success'] = false;
        $data['title'] = $blogTitle;
        $data['authorID'] = $authorID;
        $data['content'] = $content;
        $data['image'] = $image;
    } else {
        $data['success'] = true;
        $data['redirect'] = '../pages/blog.php';
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: For a start, trim your code. Answers where the entirety of the code is passed rarely get a lot of help. Just post the code we need to see.

Comment: @Whathaveyoutried url is correct.

Comment: @Utkanos i'm not sure where the problem is? and i have included all code cause in most cases everyone ask's for more code if i just include one language.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the exchanged data eg with Firebug?

Comment: http://sscce.org/...

Comment: @fvu i hadn't, but thanks a ton for opening my eyes to that!! i noticed some errors coming back about a foreign key constrait that i hadn't seen before but it didnt effect the process, my ajax syntax was not correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preventDefault function is a variable that does not exist (event) use only "e" there. In the "data" variable names, use double quotes. Do not use: data: {variable: variable} use: data: {variable: value}. Ie, variable and value with different names.

```
$("#ajax-publish-blog").click(function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var titleBlog = $('#edit-blog-title').val();
    var contenido = $('#edit-blog-content').val();
    var image = $('.create-a-blog #hero').css('background-image');
    var cleanup = /\"|\'|\)/g;
    var bg = image.split('/').pop().replace(cleanup, '');
    var IDauthor = $('input[name=author]').val();
    console.log("Blog Title = " + titleBlog + " // Blog Content = " + contentido + " // bg image = " + bg + " // authorID =" + IDauthor);

    $.ajax({
        url: "../process/post-blog-process2.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: { 'blogTitle': titleBlog, 'content': contenido, 'image': bg, 'authorID': IDauthor },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            alert("ohyer" + " " + data.titleBlog + " " + data.IDauthor + " " + data.contenido + " " + data.image) 
        },
        error: function(data) {
            alert("ohno" + " " + data.titleBlog + " " + data.IDauthor + " " + data.contenido + " " + data.image)
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Try adding at least a bit of explanation with your answer.

Comment: What is your answer ... ?

Comment: I changed the name of some variables, and added quotes in the "date". Here worked properly.

Comment: downside? why? i dont understand.

Comment: Not my downvote, but a wad of code with just "Here, try this" is not considered a proper answer on SO.  Explain WHAT you changed, and WHY it solves OP's problem.